# Google analytics tracking for Virtuemart in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, e-commerce, analytics, tracking, virtuemart

I've got a serious issue with tracking ecommerce analytical data in google for my client's Joomla! site. The plugins that I've found available are shoddy and only work very inconsistently.

I'm currently using Virtuemart within the Joomla! site and have installed the 'Artio' plugin. http://www.artio.net/joomla-extensions/google-analytics-tracking-code-for-joomla but the information comes in sporadically and seemingly randomly.

Is there another way? Is there a way to fix the Artio plugin? Does it have to further coded manually?

The site is http://www.stjeans.com

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that its definately the plugin and not some permission or errors? Check logs first :)

Comment: I have NOT checked that out and am thankful that you have mentioned that. I think that it's highly likely there could be a permission conflict now that you mention it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same frustrations with various plugins, so ended up with a module called Google Analytics Tracking Module from the JED, and followed the clearly described steps from Google Analystics to [Set Up Ecommerce Tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009612&topic=1037061&ctx=topic%3C/div%3E) with ***great*** success.